# X-ming, Ubuntu apps - getting the Ubuntu style/theme to load

Tags: ubuntu, x-windows, xming

I am running X-ming on Windows 7 and using putty to ssh into an Ubuntu system.
On the Ubuntu system I use the command:

$ gnome-terminal &

to display a terminal back on the Windows box.

When I do this I don't get the standard Ubuntu style, i.e. dark purple background, Mono font, solid cursor (which I've configured in the Gnome Control Center.) Instead I get a very plain style - white background, blinking cursor, very small font.

However, if I run `gnome-control-center` and then click on, say, the Keyboard icon, the terminal window will be reconfigured with the Ubuntu style with my customizations (e.g. block cursor vs. blinking cursor.) Just starting one of the control applets seems to trigger this style change.

My question is: How can I trigger this style change more directly - without having to launch the Gnome Control center and launching one of the configuration applets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **`gnome-settings-daemon`** – which should be somewhere in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/libexec` depending on your Ubuntu release...

```
find /usr/lib* -name "gnome-settings-daemon" -type f
```

---

For font size, it might be necessary to add `-dpi 96` to the Xming command line, since that's what Xorg uses by default (while Xming defaults to 100 DPI).